# how to configure user's custom domain in my app automatically (after they updated CNAME record in their dns settings ) i use Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, devops, digital-ocean

Wordpress, Shopify, Ghost - these apps allow their users to use a custom domain.
For example- `foo.wordpress.com` can change to `example.com`

To allow users to use custom domain they need to add CNAME record in their DNS settings
but how can I configure their domain in my app?

if there are one or two users I can change config file manually in NGINx,
but what if I have a thousand users who add custom domain through web app

What is the process for automating config files of Nginx or there is another way of doing that.

Comment: There are many ways to create and manage multi-tenant applications. We need more information about your architecture to help you with your question. How do you separate tenant data? Do you provide one instance per tenant or shared application server? How will you handle SSL Certificates? What technologies do you use? Your question is too general for me to answer.

Comment: node js server with Nginx server (reverse proxy). will use a load balancer in the future if needed.

Comment: read [here](https://www.indiehackers.com/forum/how-to-offer-custom-domains-to-my-users-cc68b6d3f3) what i want.

Comment: For Nginx the easiest way will be to create one config file per domain and execute `nginx reload`. In the configuration file it is able to map Host- Header from example.com to foo.wordress.com before forwarding the Request to nodeJs server. But with SSL Certificates and scaling it will be a pain.

Comment: any idea how can I automate creating config file per domain every time user point DNS to my server?

Comment: This is not automatable. User has to go to your site and configure the domain to route, before DNS is point to your server. On the page user is registering custom domain name you trigger configuriation file.